# Array Initialization Error? Something probably not sure

Tags: java, arrays

Even though I've been using java for a year now, I still have this gripe against arrays, I hate working with them. In an attempt to overcome it, I'm doing some practice. Anyway, I'm trying to fill an array with numbers that are either heads or tails. Here is what I got:

```
public class CoinToss{

   private int numTosses;
   private int headCount;
   private int tailCount;
   private double temp;
   private int totalTosses;

   public CoinToss(int _numTosses){
   numTosses = _numTosses;
   totalTosses=0;
   char[] tally = new char[_numTosses];
   }
   
   
   public void toss(){
   for(int i = 0;i<=numTosses;i++){
     temp = Math.random();
     if(temp<0.5){
     tally[totalTosses]='h';}
     if(temp>=0.5){
     tally[totalTosses]='t';}
     totalTosses++;
   }
   }
   
   public int getTossCount(){return totalTosses;}
   public int getHead(){return headCount;}
   public int getTail(){return tailCount;}

}
```

I'm sorry if I'm being difficult, but for the sake of practice I need to use arrays not arrayLists or what not. In terms of errors I'm getting "cannot find symbol" errors, I've been looking for a while now, but just can't seem to get it done.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what IDE are you using? Most known  ones would have immediately highlighted this error and explained it as you type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
private int numTosses;
   private int headCount;
   private int tailCount;
   private double temp;
   private int totalTosses;
   private  char[] tally; 

   public CoinToss(int _numTosses){
   numTosses = _numTosses;
   totalTosses=0;
   tally = new char[_numTosses];
```

}

or even declare and initialize in the `toss` as it is not used outside of this method

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't related to arrays. You declared tally as a local variable inside your constructor. It isn't visible in the toss method. Declare it as an instance variable like your other variables numTosses, headCount, etc